# Getting Error in Hive while running a script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am creating a temp table from another table using AS clause where i am including the partition column of another table also be part of temp table and then i am getting the below error. Below is the table create statement where col4 is the partition column of table xyz.

And while running the create statement i am getting the below error. And when i am removing the col4 from the create statement its running fine

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NumberFormatException For input string: "HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION" (state=42000,code=40000)

Please help.

Example: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE abc STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT

col1 AS col1,

col2 AS col2,

col3 AS col3,

col4 AS col4

FROM xyz;

Regards,

Vimarsh

Comment: Show your query, the data, and the table schema

Comment: please refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656133/creating-temp-table-from-another-table-including-partition-column-in-hive

Comment: Please [edit] this question rather than posting a separate one, and show your `xyz` table definition

Comment: Done. the schema of xyz is col1 string, col2 string, col3 timestamp, col4 int. And col4 is partition column which is troubling me here

Comment: In your HDFS directory, is there any path that looks like `col4=HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION`?