# Creating temp table from another table including partition column in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, partition

I am creating a temp table from another table using `AS` clause where I am including the partition column of another table also be part of temp table and then I am getting the below error. Below is the table create statement where `col4` is the partition column of table `xyz`.

And while running the create statement i am getting the below error. And when I am removing the `col4` from the create statement its running fine.

Error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NumberFormatException For
>   input string: "HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION" (state=42000,code=40000)

Please help.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE abc STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT
col1 AS col1,
col2 AS col2,
col3 AS col3,
col4 AS col4
FROM xyz;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error in Hive while running a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647217/getting-error-in-hive-while-running-a-script)

Comment: What happens when you just selecting from xyz?

Comment: it works fine, only when i create a tmp table from partitioned table it gives error. Now issue got resolved as i added where condition on partition column in the above script . FROM xyz where col4>201802

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with source table `xyz` because it contains partition `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`

Hive creates a partition with value `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` when in dynamic partition mode inserted partition value is NULL.

Partition `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` is not compatible with numeric type and this causing error because it cannot be cast to numeric type.

To remove or query this partition, you need to change the column type to string first:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz PARTITION COLUMN (col4 string);
```

Of course you may want to backup table and check the data before removing and decide what to do with this data.

To remove partition:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz DROP PARTITION (col4 = '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');
```

After removing partition you can change the type of partition column back to numeric type.